# Coloured Line Detection Using AForge

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition, aforge

I have a requirement to scan various images for coloured lines, the result of this determines what we do with an image, no lines = delete, lines = save.

I have been meeting this requirement adequately by simply comparing the colour of each pixel to a list of known colours that we are looking for, if we find above a certain threshold of pixels then we are happy that there is something on the image that we are interested in.

I recently had to re-work this as we started to get highly compressed Jpegs and (for example) the red line ended up being made up of hundreds of shades of red - I got this working reliably but the process got me thinking that there mush be a better way so I have started to look at AForge to determine if it could be used to detect the different coloured lines.

I have spent a day looking into it and *think* that it will work but need some guidance on what the best approach/method will be as CV is a very big field and I only need to learn a very small part of it for the time being.

This is an example of one of the images

[image]

In this instance I'd want to find out about the red and blue lines.
I'd disregard the black ones.

Ive been reading and testing some things with hough line detection and have had some very limited success when detecting a STRAIGHT line on a black and white image but cant find many examples of detecting curved coloured lines.

All Im looking for is a little guidance on whether AForge is the best way forward (if it can even do what I want) and an idea of what the process would look like so that I can go and investigate the right things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is of use to anyone else in the future I found a way to do this, its still not perfect but has improved the reliability of our process.

Step one -> Remove all but the colour that we are interested in :

```
var c = Color.Red;
EuclideanColorFiltering filter = new EuclideanColorFiltering();
filter.CenterColor = new RGB(color.R, color.G, color.B);
filter.Radius = (short)radius;
filter.ApplyInPlace(input);
```

Step 2 -> Convert to gray scale

```
Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709.Apply(image);
```

Step 3 -> Run the result through a Hough

```
var lineTransform = new HoughLineTransformation();
lineTransform.ProcessImage(input);
HoughLine[] lines = 
lineTransform.GetLinesByRelativeIntensity(_intensity);
```

Step one pretty much yields the same result that I used to get by scanning the image for pixels of a specific colour, but the HoughLineTransform has the effect of identifying which pixels form a line - removing a lot of the noise that we had on the highly compressed JPEGS.

There is still a bit of an issue in that the way that we are filtering out all but the colours that we are interested in doesnt work for all colours, we have quite a few shades of grey that we need to identify by that picks up the outlines of roads etc, so there is still work to do - but what I describe above has got us much closer to a solution.